# How to access variable from show view

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have this in my view/index.html.erb:

```
<p>List of all counties</p>

<ul>
  <% @counties.each do |county| %>
      <li><%= link_to "Locations in #{county.name}", generate_county_url_with_prefix(county) %></li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

CountiesController:

```
class CountiesController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :extract_county_name, :only => [:show_by_name]
   def index
      @counties = County.all

   end

   def show
      @county = County.find(params[:id])

   end 

   def show_by_name
      @county = County.find_by_name(@county_name)
      render :show
   end

   private
   def extract_county_name
     @county_name = params[:county_name_with_prefix].gsub(County::ROUTE_PREFIX,"").gsub("-", " ").strip
   end      
end
```

All works fine until I try to call @locations within the counties/show.html.erb.

```
<ul>
  <% @locations.each do |location| %>
      <li><%= link_to "#{location.name}", generate_location_url_with_prefix(location) %></li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

I know this is because its not defined in the controller above, but when I do define it I get errors. How can I reference a @location variable (i.e. intention is to show all the locations that are within the county - in database) from this show view?

Many thanks

Comment: You are correct that you have to define `@locations` in you controller to access it in the view. Can you post how you've tried to define the variable as well as the error(s) you got?

Comment: Showing /home/ubuntu/workspace/static_site/app/views/counties/show.html.erb where line #6 raised:

undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass
Extracted source (around line #6):
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
          
  
  
  <ul>
    <% @locations.each do |location| %>
        <li><%= link_to "#{location.name}", generate_location_url_with_prefix(location) %></li>
    <% end %>
  </ul>

Comment: added this to my counties controller in def show method: @locations = Location.where("counties_id = #{params[:id]}").all

Comment: How were you trying to define @locations in your controller?  can you post that code? From your error, it seems your query was not finding anything, hence the NilClass.

Comment: @user3735114 try `@locations = @county.locations`

Comment: I have updated my controller in the show method with that in the show def and still the same error

Comment: Could you update your question with what you're actually trying at the moment. That's not clear to me. You may also want to add your models.

Answer (score 0):

You need to populate a session or global variable on your Counties controller with the data you want to iterate on.

Show Method (Counties Controller)

```
@locations = Location.where("county_id = #{params[:id]}").all
```

Something like that.

Comment: You'd want to use `county_id` instead of `countie_id`. Regardless, assuming that County `has_many` Locations, you could just do `@locations = @county.locations`.

Comment: What if `params[:id]` is a string like `"12; DROP TABLE users;"`? Well, the `users` table would be dropped. SQL injection!

Comment: To avoid the mentioned SQL injection problem, `Location.where('county_id = ?', params[:id])` or `Location.where(county_id: params[:id])` would be better.

Comment: I'm afraid these solutions aren't working - when I try to refereance @location in the counties show view it spits out exactly the same error, even though I have defined it in the counties controller ? Totally baffled

Comment: Sounds like we need a better idea of your models and what is in your database since, assuming you have a field called `county_id` on the `Location` model, you should be at least getting back an empty `ActiveRecord::Relation`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure the issue here was Cloud 9 ide not saving files properly thus creating a pretty perplexing scenario (for a newbie to rails). It appeared as though I had (more or less) the right code in place to allow me to call @locations from the county controller (and yes database column/data set up supported this):

```
class CountiesController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :extract_county_name, :only => [:show_by_name]
   def index
      @counties = County.all
      @locations = Location.all

   end

   def show
      @county = County.find(params[:id])
      @locations = Location.all
```